# How do I use a Django custom template tag in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I’ve written a custom template tag:

```
def mytag(para):
    return something
```

In my template I am getting a value `{{value}}`. Now I am using `{{value|mytag}}` to apply the tag to the value, and it is throwing a syntax error.

Comment: -1. Is there any reason you can't read the extremely clear documentation?

Comment: @Daniel: maybe Alis misunderstood the documentation — what’s clear to one person isn’t always clear to everyone else. Is there any reason you can’t ignore questions you think are too simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use template tags in Django, you wrap the name of the tag in `{%` and `%}`, like this:

```
{% mytag %}
```

If your tag takes a parameter, as yours seems to, you pass the parameter after the name of the tag:

```
{% mytag value %}
```

The syntax you were trying to use — `{{ value|mytag }}` is for template *filters*, not tags.

- Template tags:

  - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#tags
  - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags
- Template filters:

  - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#filters
  - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Answer (score 5):

Your example looks like a filter. If that's all you want, it's fairly simple. Paul's links to the documentation should provide a fairly clear explanation of how and why to do things. Here's a quick start that should get you up and running though.

1. Create a folder in your app called "templatetags" with an empty __init__.py file
2. Create a file to hold your custom tags, we'll say "tags.py" for now.

your tags.py file should look something like this:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def mytag(para):
    return 'something'
```

then, in your template, you'll first have to load your custom tags, then you can have access to it.

```
{% load tags %}

My new value is: {{ value|mytag }}
```